# Link multiple "like" buttons to the same thing

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins, xfbml

We have a facebook page for our company, and we have a company website.

I want the website and facebook page to be recognized as the same object in facebook so that when someone goes on the website and clicks the like button, they will be "likeing" our company page.

Also, I want to be able to have custom links given for what shows up in someone's feed, so when their friends visit the site the url will include a GET variable containing their referer's ID.  I'll describe the ideal scenario below:

1. Steven goes to http://www.thaibrains.com.
2. He enter's his e-mail in $6000 giveaway contest, 
   and is told that for each person he additionally signs up, he'll receive an extra entry.
3. The page provide's a like button to help him spread the word.
4. Steven clicks the like button, and on his wall it shows steven liked a link
5. Steven's friend clicks on the link, which navigates them to http://www.thaibrains.com/?ref=7456899  (the url contains steven's referer ID so he get's credit for this sign up)
6. Steven's friend Tony repeats the process, but when friends of tony click on the link in his feed, they go to a url with tony's ref id.

When I go to the thaibrains facebook page, I should see everyone that clicked the like button on the website listed as liking the facebook page.  My two problems though are that when I provide urls with different ref numbers in it, it's viewed as a different object and doesn't show previous likes.

Facebook documentation is pretty horrible imho, but if there's a specific part I should be reading that I may not have found feel free to link me and i'll put in my diligent reading

Comment: So to be clear, you want all the pages counted separately, but then also counted together? I'm rather sure facebook's API does not allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

> want the website and facebook page to be recognized as the same object
>   in facebook so that when someone goes on the website and clicks the
>   like button, they will be "likeing" our company page.

You will have to add them together yourself, as the API doesn't allow for tracking them together.

For the second question, it seems to be close to be against facebook policy, so I'm not going to attempt to address that one.  Plus, on stackoverflow we like to keep one question to having one question.  :)